# Заполнить таблицу по спирали Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть матрица NxN, и мне нужно заполнить ее по убыванию по спирали из первого элемента (числа, содержащие «6», не отображаются) Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом мне заполнить такую таблицу в Android, если каждый элемент должен отображаться по спирали после небольшой задержки? Что мне использовать? Единственное решение, которое я пока смог придумать - это в цикле программно создавать TextView и в метод setText() передавать значение числа, которым должен заполниться элемент матрицы и размещать его под предыдущим TextView - если мы идем вниз, справа от предыдущего - если идем вправо и тд. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что должен быть более красивый и правильный способ это сделать.

Матрица может быть размером N=0 to 1000(размер матрицы: NxN) - как реализовать такую большую матрицу на экране смартфона? Может быть использовать ScrollView в обе стороны или какое-нибудь масштабирование?

Comment: Изначально вам надо просто получить List значений, отсортированных по специальному алгоритму. Гляньте тут https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-n-x-n-spiral-matrix-using-o1-extra-space/ Чутка подрефакторить придется. Но это не сложно. Динамически textView тут создавать не надо, достаточно уже готовый лист поместить в gridView, ну или в recyclerView с GridLayoutManager, у которого columnNumber будет равен значению вашего заданного n.

Comment: Да, но как мне задать порядок отображения элементов? Написать Custom Layout Manager, где задать порядок отрисовки элементов? Есть ли где-нибудь примеры подобного подхода?